# Selecting morphological components, of a certain size, centered on points of interest in an image

Tags: image-processing, image

I have a set of points in an image, for example:

```
POI = {{32.5, 257.5}, {73., 250.5}, {55.5, 248.5}, {209., 246.5}, {186.5, 245.5}, {154.5, 241.}, {213.5, 235.5}, {169.5, 233.5}, {212.5, 233.5}, {104., 231.5}, {18., 229.5}, {93., 228.5}, {203.5, 227.5}, {109.5, 224.5}, {138., 223.5}, {222., 222.}, {208.5, 218.5}, {0.5, 210.5}, {65.5, 209.5}, {98.5, 208.5}, {7.16667, 205.167}, {30.5, 205.5}, {257., 205.5}, {88., 203.}, {210., 202.5}, {246.5, 203.5}, {257.5, 199.}, {40.5, 198.5}, {217.5, 198.5}, {193.5, 197.5}, {0.5, 195.5}, {44.5, 192.5}, {159.5, 188.}, {120.75, 185.}, {39.8333, 183.833}, {207., 184.}, {239., 184.5}, {178.5, 183.5}, {52.5, 182.5}, {19.3, 178.9}, {155.5, 180.5}, {167.5, 179.5}, {19.5, 174.5}, {89.5, 174.}, {206.5, 173.5}, {44., 169.5}, {32.5, 169.}, {130.5, 168.5}, {106.833, 166.833}, {202.9, 165.7}, {215.167, 164.833}, {231.5, 165.5}, {46.5, 164.5}, {242.5, 164.5}, {200.5, 160.5}, {255., 155.5}, {108.5, 154.5}, {197.167, 154.167}, {192., 153.}, {10.5, 151.5}, {32.5, 149.5}, {111.3, 146.3}, {136.5, 147.5}, {187.5, 147.5}, {257.5, 146.5}, {63.1667, 146.167}, {122.5, 144.}, {135.5, 144.5}, {177., 144.}, {218.5, 144.5}, {26.1667, 143.167}, {211.5, 141.5}, {188.5, 140.5}, {106.833, 137.833}, {0.5, 136.5}, {29., 136.}, {98.5, 135.5}, {185.5, 134.5}, {145.5, 133.5}, {113.5, 131.5}, {219., 130.5}, {70., 129.5}, {11.1667, 128.167}, {183.5, 128.5}, {63.5, 125.5}, {60.5, 124.}, {85.5, 124.5}, {67.5, 122.5}, {43.5, 121.}, {182.5, 121.5}, {155.5, 119.5}, {252.5, 119.5}, {124., 118.5}, {97.5, 117.5}, {45., 115.5}, {104.167, 114.833}, {69.5, 112.}, {40.5, 111.5}, {117.5, 111.}, {1., 110.}, {34.5, 109.5}, {189.5, 109.5}, {32.1667, 107.833}, {100.5, 106.5}, {45.5, 105.5}, {106.5, 104.5}, {205.5, 104.}, {167.5, 103.}, {173.5, 103.5}, {185.5, 102.5}, {123.5, 95.5}, {181.5, 95.}, {45.5, 94.5}, {26.5, 87.5}, {74.5, 86.5}, {179., 86.5}, {93.5, 83.}, {188.5, 83.5}, {13.5, 80.5}, {75.5, 79.5}, {41.5, 78.5}, {162.5, 78.5}, {9.83333, 76.1667}, {179.5, 76.5}, {151.5, 74.5}, {182., 72.5}, {141.167, 67.1667}, {235.5, 66.5}, {156., 64.5}, {167.5, 64.5}, {212.5, 64.5}, {199.833, 60.8333}, {157.5, 60.}, {121.5, 54.}, {198.5, 54.5}, {83.5, 48.5}, {179.5, 46.5}, {228.5, 46.5}, {127., 44.5}, {204.5, 44.5}, {35.5, 42.5}, {79.5, 41.5}, {66.5, 40.5}, {80.8333, 38.8333}, {190.5, 38.5}, {51., 36.5}, {243.5, 31.5}, {93., 29.5}, {232.5, 29.5}, {232.5, 22.5}, {35.5, 20.5}, {121.5, 20.5}, {159., 17.5}, {219.5, 14.5}, {253.5, 13.}, {214.5, 11.5}, {77.5, 9.5}, {7.,8.5}, {168., 8.5}, {219.833, 6.83333}, {83.8333, 4.83333}, {22.5, 3.}, {140.5, 0.5}, {227.5, 0.5}, {253.5, 0.5}};
```

I would like to generate rectangular morphological components (compatible with ComponentMeasurements) of a certain size that are centered on each of these points.  Specifically, I would like the components to have a side length of $l$ pixels, and where each point in the morphological component is at most a fixed Manhattan distance $d_{max}$ away from its centerpoint.

How might I do this, perhaps using Dilate?  And is it possible to have overlapping morphological components?

Update : Answer to the last point on whether components can overlap: No (see comment by belisarius below).

Update 2 : The command:

```
Dilation[Components, r]
```

Will take a single pixel, and blow it up it up into a square block with $r$ pixels on either side of the centerpoint.  If there were some manner of generating a single-pixel component at each of my POI positions, I believe that would solve my problem.  Is there an easy manner of doing this?

Comment: Components are disconnected. In fact, that is the _definition_ of component ... a disconnected area

Comment: @belisarius Thanks - I've noted your answer to that part of my question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see two possible pitfalls here. The first one is, that your coordinates are not integers > 0. This is problematic, because a *point in an image* is per definition a pixel which has always integer coordinates. What you could do here is multiply your coordinates by 10 and round the values to integers. In this way you get at least rid of the .5 coordinates.

Another problem is, that you need to be careful with the distance $d_{max}$ you are using, because if two positions in your array happen to be too close together, they get merged into one *morphological component*. This is probably not what you want.

The rest is simple: Use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) to create a pixel-matrix which is 1 at the positions you specified. Make an image from it and use [`Dilation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dilation.html). With your points `POI` defined the following one-liner works

```
Dilation[Image@SparseArray[Round[POI] + 1 -> 1], 2]
```

The `+1 is necessary because arrays in *Mathematica* indexed starting by 1 and your coordinates contain values 0.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another approach you may wanna try is using a combination of [`DistanceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistanceTransform.html) and [`Binarize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Binarize.html)

[image]

```
With[{img = Image@SparseArray[Round[2 POI] + 1 -> 1]},
 Manipulate[
  ColorNegate@
   Binarize[
    DistanceTransform[ColorNegate[img], 
      DistanceFunction -> distFunc] // ImageAdjust, t],
  {t, 0, .5},
  {distFunc, {EuclideanDistance, SquaredEuclideanDistance, 
    ManhattanDistance, ChessboardDistance}, 
   ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
 ]
```

### More Details

> why do we write: "Round[2 POI]" in the second part

Let me explain this further. Assume you have two points in your data `{1.5,2}` and `{2,2}`. For the pixel matrix, we need integer coordinates. If we simply use `Round` here, we end up with the two points being the same.

By a simple scaling of all coordinates with 2, we ensure these two points stay distinct: `{3,4}` and `{4,4}`. Since your `POI` list contains things like `9.83333` a final `Round` is still necessary.

What you have to keep in mind is, that the coordinate transformation we used

```
Round[2 POI] + 1
```

scales and shifts your coordinate system. To come back to your original system, you have to invert this by `(p-1)/2` when `p` is a pixel-position from your image.

> Also, shouldn't: `Dilation[Image@SparseArray[Round[POI] + 1 -> 1], 2]` be `Dilation[Image@SparseArray[Floor[POI] + 1 -> 1], 2]`?

I wouldn't know why you *should* use `Floor`, but you surely can do this. `Round` is just more exact, because a coordinate `12.9991` gets converted to 13 and not 12.

> I've found this correction mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/… to be necessary in terms of matching up the coordinates for the morphological components in your answer and the original POI coordinates taken from my image of interest. Why is that?

In addition to the coordinate transform we did, you have to understand, that `Image` uses a reversed system and the coordinates coming [`ComponentMeasurments`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComponentMeasurments.html) are transposed. Furthermore, measures like `"Centroid"` give half-pixel coordinates.

Here an example where input and output matches:

```
mycoords = {{55, 10}, {230, 45}};
img = Image[Reverse@Transpose@SparseArray[mycoords -> 1, {256, 256}]]
ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalComponents[img], "Centroid"]
(* {1 -> {229.5, 44.5}, 2 -> {54.5, 9.5}}*)
```

Comment: how do you create these cool animated gifs?

Comment: @bills This is a small app that comes with Ubuntu. Nothing special.

Comment: @halirutan Great answer!  However, why do we write: "Round[2 POI]" in the second part?

Comment: @halirutan Also, shouldn't: Dilation[Image@SparseArray[Round[POI] + 1 -> 1], 2] be Dilation[Image@SparseArray[Floor[POI] + 1 -> 1], 2]?

Comment: @halirutan I've found this correction http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/a-rotation-like-transform-on-a-matrix to be necessary in terms of matching up the coordinates for the morphological components in your answer and the original POI coordinates taken from my image of interest.  Why is that?

Comment: @Intemediocre See my edit at the end of the answer.